# no intel driver loading but intel driver installed no 3d effects vesa only works

Tags: intel

I have Asus laptop x55sx161d. When I try to install Ubuntu 13.10 it automatically switch off. Then I added `nomodeset`, I installed it but no Unity 3d desktop. I checked it is not loading Intel driver installed but using Vesa only. I tried all methods almost by referring Google but nothing works, it shows:

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

One more news when I added `acpi=off`, it loads `intel` but shutdown is problem hanging.

My previous Ubuntu 11.10 loaded `intel` driver with 3d effects with no problem but why latest Ubuntu not loading my installed Intel driver properly?

This is happing for Debian 7 too, there no `acpi=off` also not loading `intel` installed driver with 3d effects. For Mesa and all libraries, I installed and reinstalled packages and reconfigure also, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Linux Intel integrated graphics drivers from Intel [Downloads here.](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010512.htm)
Select the appropriate driver based on your processor's video, HD2500, HD3000, HD4000, etc.

You may also need to update your micrcode for your specific processor.

Use the Synaptics Package Manager. If you do not find the Synaptics Package Manager in your applications.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Use the search to find microcode, check intel-microcode, iucode-tool and microcode.ctl.  Click Apply (green check mark) then reboot for the changes to be installed.

It made a noticeable difference on my Asus laptop.

Comment: boss I tried you told but not working

Comment: What is your hardware configuration? CPU model number, RAM, BIOS version, GPU model (if integrated graphics, CPU model will indicate), please post that information so you can get some help.

Comment: Brand Asus
Series X55C
Model ID X55C-SX161D
Processor
Processor Pentium Dual Core (3rd Gen)
Variant 2020M
Chipset Mobile HM70 Express
Brand Intel
Clock Speed 2.4 GHz
Cache 2 MB
System Memory 4GB DDR3
Storage
Hardware Interface SATA
RPM 5400
HDD Capacity 500 GB
System Architecture 64 bit
Display
Screen Size 15.6 inch
Resolution 1366 x 768 Pixel
Screen Type HD Glare Display with LED Backlit
Graphics
Graphic Processor Intel HD GDDR3raphics

Comment: Intel lists only one Graphics driver for Pentium HD graphics for Linus. You can find it => https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop+graphics+drivers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Pentium%C2%AE+Processors+with+Intel%C2%AE+HD+Graphics&ProdId=3524&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39